# How do i enforce signed jar verification before cf push?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a way to enforce the signed jar verification for cf push?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking if the `cf` CLI can verify a signed jar before it pushes the jar to CF? The JRE should be verifying the jar now when the app is started.

Comment: Use a CI/CD pipeline.  Define a step that verifies your JAR is signed, maybe even define a step that signs it, and then do a `cf push`.  You JAR will be signed or the pipeline will fail.  For what it's worth, `cf push` is going to explode your JAR file, extract all the files and push them up separately.  The target JAR/WAR file (i.e. what's referenced by `path` or `-p`) never makes it to the server, just the contents of that file.

Comment: Thanks guys, Yes i want to verify signed jar before it get pushed to CF. I dont want to tell my developers to write it in pipeline as a stage before "cf push". I want to do it seamlessly without modifying pipeline. I hope, i make sense.